# XmlHttpRequest Progress Eventhandler Compatibility in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, progress

My current AJAX application using jQuery looks as follows (simplified):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somefile',
    timeout : timeOutVar,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

I updated that code to use the `progress` eventhandler as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somefile',
    timeout : timeOutVar,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            console.log('progress');
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

That works perfectly in Internet Explorer 10 and all other modern browsers. However, in older Internet Explorer version, I encountered a problem. IE9,8,7 do not call the `progress` eventhandler, but `success` when everything is loaded.

So I wonder whether there are any compatibility issues in these older Internet Explorer versions. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any resource which exactly defines which parts of `XmlHttpRequest` work in which IE version. Does anybody know such a resource or what might be wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks instead override xhr implementation.

Comment: Defining the `progress` eventhandler in `beforeSend` does not work, probably because jQuery itself does not support `progress`.